# How to change backoffice ui in ext-backoffice-config.xml file

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I am new in Hybris, sorry if it is silly question. 
I have existing project and I am trying to figure out how to change  backoffice ui.  I need to change 'backoffice > Order > Orders'. I tried modifying cus_ext-backoffice-config.xml file. But it did not change anything.

1. Can someone please tell me if I am modifying right file.
2. Is there any way I can interact backoffice through hmc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset zk framework cache. Press F4 in backoffice, then click reset everything option in right top of corner menu. Press F4 again for return normal screen.

Comment: is there any way to do it from the console? I want to update the dropdown list with widgets(admin, product cockpit etc.) with ant commands. ant update with properties not working.

Comment: May be you will try deleting cached files for backoffice. I think there is olse service for it, you can debug backoffice for finding reset everything button. Then call service with groovy.